# Some highways segments ignored by osm2po?

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po, route

Where i can read why some roads/segments are disappear from routing? We are trying to comment all "wtr.deny" rules in config file, but nothing changed.
Examples added as links bellow.
[Screenshot1](http://imageshack.us/a/img829/1516/screenshot1ew.png)
[Screenshot2](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/9407/screenshot2jx.png)

Comment: Instead, maybe you could try to replacing deny with allow? Also, I think you have to rebuild your graph each time you make a change to the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal road, so you do not need to modify the config.
I've debugged it and the reason is simple:
The road has been imported as gpx and thus is very long.
It is recommended that when adding roads to OSM he or she should manually correct the data, e.g. add intersections, split it into shorter logigcal units, etc.

**Solution** (depending on your data size):

increase osm2po's **tileSize** parameter to sth. like:

`tileSize=x` (if your extract is small or you have lots of RAM)

or

`tileSize=5x5,1` (if your extract is big)

Answer (score 0):

**Tipp:**

osm2po reports this kind of error in its **log** (file and console):

Look for messages like this one:

```
WARN   2 of 36 ways could not be resolved
       Maybe tileSize and/or tileBuffer are too small.
```